# Serialization and Deserialization of Subclasses with spray-json

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

assume I have one base class B and two subclasses S1 and S2.

I want serialize and deserialize class S1 and S2.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is it possible two write a JsonFormat for class B and use it in class S1 and S2 for serialization?
2. I want two deserialize class S1 and S2. But I do not know if the json String represents class S1 or S2, so I think I can not use spray-json method convertTo because I have to know the exact type I want to deserialize.

My solution to 2. would be to write a wrapper class which contains the a string for the type (S1 or S2) and the json String for S1 or S2. Is this the best way two go or are there other better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but your format won't (and can't) serialize any details of `S1` or `S2` that aren't part of `B`.

I'd suggest having separate formats for `S1` and `S2` and then a custom format for `B` that delegates to the appropriate format:

```
implicit val s1Format = jsonFormat3(S1) //assuming S1 and S2 are case classes
implicit val s2Format = jsonFormat5(S2) //with 3 and 5 parameters respectively
implicit object bFormat extends RootJsonFormat[B] {
  //assuming both objects have a field called "myTypeField"
  def read(jv: JsValue) = jv.asJsObject.fields("myTypeField") match {
      case JsString("s1") => jv.convertTo[S1]
      case JsString("s2") => jv.convertTo[S2]
    }
  def write(b: B) = b match {
    case s1: S1 => s1Format.write(s1)
    case s2: S2 => s2Format.write(s2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. Question 1. is still not completely solved. S1 and S2 are not case classes, so I have to write my own formatter. No problem. But B also contains some properties, f.e. "myTypeField". Any solution how to implement this. I can not derive s1Format from bFormat or can I somehow?

Comment: You could e.g. call `bFormat` and then copy the resulting `JsObject` and add more `fields` to it. But IMO that's likely to be quite fragile. Have you considered a composition approach? i.e. rather than extending `B`, `S1` and `S2` could instead both have a field of type `B` (and delegate certain methods to it).

Comment: Delegation is not elegant either in my case. I have implemented something similar to your suggestion. My JsonProtocoll contains a method which generates a map with default data from B. To this map I add properties from S1 in the s1Format#write and generate the JsObject from this map. Not that beautiful, but it works for me.